# Good references(books or lecture notes) for self study on Banach Algebra.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, soft-question, banach-algebras

Can someone suggest some good references(books or lecture notes) for self study on Banach Algebra?

By background being a first course in Functional Analysis and a course in Measure Theory.

Most preferably other than some of known to be:

- Rudin,  Functional Analysis.
- Conway, Functional Analysis.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the book by Richard V. Kadison/John R. Ringrose, *Fundamentals of the Theory of Operator Algebras Volume I*, and you may pair this one with another book by Corneliu Constantinescu, *$C^{\ast}$-algebras Volume II*.

These two books assume little background of measure theory, they even do not assume very much about Functional Analysis, so I think they suit for your need.

Comment: I second the Kadison / Ringrose. I'd also recommend John B Conway's "A Course in Functional Analysis"

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest a few good books for this:

- W. Arveson's *A short course on Spectral Theory*
- R. Douglas' *Banach Algebra Techniques in Operator theory*
- G. Murphy's *C-star algebras and Operator theory*